# TYPO3 : send data from extension to the backend layout

Tags: typo3

I made an extension which display some data and I need to send them to my Layout.

In my file list.html I made a left column with some data, but finally I need this column in my layout.

there is some code :

Layouts/MyLayout.html

```
<f:render partial="Structure/Header" arguments="{_all}"/>
<f:render partial="Menus/Main" arguments="{_all}"/>
<!--the left column should be here -->
<f:render section="default" />
```

List.html

```
<f:layout name="Default"/>
<f:section name="main">
<aside>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <ul>
            <f:for each="{Mydata}" as="data">
                <li>{data.title}</li>
            </f:for>
        </ul>
</aside>
</f:section>
```

That's why I would need to retrieve my extension data in my layout. It is possible to get I ?

If it's not possible, it is possible to get in list.html the name of the actual backend layout with some typoscript ?

Comment: From inside the controller you can send anything to your layout.
It's also possible to create some TyppoScript like `lib.someLibObject` and read the TypoScript from inside the template with `<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.someLibObject" />`

Comment: the lib.someLibObject should be writed to the setup of my extension to get data ? I tried to do that  in my setup.ts of my extension  : lib.test = TEXT
lib.test.value = mytest and  <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.title" /> in my layout page but I didn't get it

Comment: `lib.someObject` is TypoScript and you can add it to any TypoScript that is included in your site. In the simplest case you just enter it in the setup field in the TypoScript-record on the root-page of your domain.
Here is the description of the viewHelper: https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/11.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/CObject.html

Comment: excuse me, could you give an answer with a small example? I'm new to typo3 and I can't find examples to use the lib, I've never used any for the moment and I admit that I have a little trouble recovering data with this method

Comment: Actually you wrote the small example by yourself already: `lib.test = TEXT lib.test.value = mytest`. You only have to assign it to some page part, like `page.10 < lib.test`. Instead of 10 you can use any number that is not used yet to get an output first. Later you can assign it to the distinct part where you need it, but the target is anyway to assign it in the fluid-template and not directly per TypoScript to the page-Object,

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to handle whether there are data for an additional column in layout.

first:
Even if in FLUID the files are stored in three folder (`Layouts/`, `Partials/`, `Templates/`) you are not forced to use it in that way. Meaning: you also can decide the layout in the template files.

In the default layout you just render a `main`section (from the template file). And in the different templates you decide whether a side column exist.

second:
extension data can be provided in multiple ways:

You can do the rendering completely in typoscript - or you use a content element with a plugin. The later would be more transparent for editors.
In your case you can provide a different BackEnd layout where editors can put a plugin in the additional column for that special 'layout'.
The rendering only occurs if that 'layout' is selected and a plugin is stored in that column.